# Filling in backticks in function

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset at hand, and I'm analyzing this with R. In my analysis, I attempted to create a function to calculate the mean of each column (column_name) based on a specified grouping column (group_name). The column_name is enclosed in backticks. Here's the initial attempt:

```
   group_mean <- data %>%
    group_by(`group_name`) %>%
    summarise(group_variance = mean(`column_name`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

When I manually type in the column name, I get a data frame where each group has different means, which is the expected behavior. However, I would like to create a function to dynamically change the column_name. If I provide the column name as a string, then I get back a data frame where each group has the same mean. Here's what I'd like the function to look like:

```
group_mean_function <- function(group_name, column_name){
 group_mean <- data %>%
 group_by(...) %>%
 summarise(group_variance = mean(..., na.rm = TRUE))
```

}
I hope this clarifies my issue. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Wrong duplicate but check this out: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-